# Keep rows based in more than 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a database similar to the one I created below (with 982977 rows × 10 columns), and I wanted to keep the rows where the exams of the same patient (ID) that are different from "COVID" have been performed in a specific period based on the date of the "COVID" exam.

I created 2 columns, one with dates 7 days before and one with 30 days after the original exam date.
Ex: If the patient had an iron exam between 7 days before and 30 days after the date of their COVID exam, then I would keep that patient, otherwise, I would remove.

I did a for loop, but since the database is big, it took almost 6h to complete and when it finished, I lost the connection to the server, and I couldn't continue to manipulate the data

Is there a simpler and/or faster way to do this?

```
ID = ['1','1','1','2','2']
Exam = ['COVID', 'Iron', 'Ferritin', 'COVID', 'Iron']
Date = [2021-02-22,2021-02-20,2021-06-22,2021-05-22,2021-05-29]
Date7 = [2021-02-15,2021-02-13,2021-06-15,2021-05-15,2021-05-22]
Date30 = [2021-03-24,2021-03-22,2021-07-24,2021-05-22,2021-06-29]

teste = list(zip(ID, Exam, Date, Date7, Date30))

teste2 = pd.DataFrame(teste, columns=['ID','Exam','Date', 'Date7', 'Date30'])
```

All the dates columns are in datetime already

```
pacients = []
for pacient in teste2.ID.unique():
    a = teste2[teste2.ID==pacient]
    b = a[a.Exam!="COVID"]
    c = a[a.Exam=="COVID"]
    for exam_covid in b.Data:
        for covid_7 in c.Data7:
            for covid_30 in c.Data30:
                if covid_7 < exam_covid < covid_30:
                    pacients.append(pacient)
pacients = set(pacientes)
pacients = list(pacientes)
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that every pacient (ID) has a unique COVID exam?

Answer (score 0):

With the following sample dataframe named `df`

```
ID = ['1','1','1','2','2']
Exam = ['COVID', 'Iron', 'Ferritin', 'COVID', 'Iron']
Date = ['2021-02-22','2021-02-20','2021-06-22','2021-05-22','2021-06-29']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'Exam': Exam, 'Date': pd.to_datetime(Date)})
```

you could try the following:

1. Step: Create a dataframe `df_cov` that covers all the time intervals around the Covid exams:

```
df_cov = df[['ID', 'Date']][df.Exam.eq('COVID')]
df_cov = df_cov.assign(
    Before=df_cov.Date - pd.Timedelta(days=7),
    After=df_cov.Date + pd.Timedelta(days=30)
).drop(columns='Date')
```

2. Step: [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the non-Covid-exams in `df` with `df_cov` on the column `ID`, then select the exams that are within the intervals (here with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)), and then extract the remaining unique `ID`s:

```
patients = (
    df[df.Exam.ne('COVID')].merge(df_cov, on='ID', how='left')
    .query('(Before < Date) & (Date < After)')
    .ID.unique()
)
```

Result for the sample (I've changed the last exam date such that it won't fall into the required time interval):

```
array(['1'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me!
After doing what you told me, I transformed the patients array into dataframe and filtered my original dataframe with only those patients. I got the result I expected.